# fabricJS stringifying an object changes its semantics

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

When adding a filter to my objects in the canvas, I create a filter which I add into index no. 6 in the object's `filter` attribute.

When getting objects from my canvas using the `let obj = canvas.getObjects()` method and accessing the filter attribute I get a value of this type: `[empty × 6, klass]`. Expanding the array in dev tools gives me:

```
6: klass {matrix: Array(20), type: 'ColorMatrix'}
length: 7
```

However, the very moment I run `JSON.stringify` either like this `JSON.stringify(obj))` or like this I get returned:

```
"filters":[{"type":"ColorMatrix","matrix":[0.41176,0.41176,0.41176,0,0,0.70915,0.70915,0.70915,0,0,0.28431,0.28431,0.28431,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]}
```

Which is semantically identical, other than the fact that the filter has been moved to index no. 0.

This is causing some problems for me, so I am wondering why this is happening and what the best practice is if I would like to maintain perfectly semantic and identical JSON representation of the object?

Comment: What problem?  JSON.stringify turns an object into a string representation.

Comment: The problem is that in its object representation the value is kept in the 6th index of the array, but `JSON.stringify` collapses the array and puts the value on the first non-empty position, which is at index 0.

When I subsequently run `JSON.parse` on the resulting string, I get a JSON that no longer accurately represents the object I started with.